# MS excel mentioned formula giving result true or false that should be a number

Tags: windows-7

=IF(OR(E17="Friday",E17="Saturday"),C17<711,6.14*I17)

The result should be number instead of true or false can anyone has solution, except condition formatting because I've tried that the result still is same.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(OR(E17="Friday",E17="Saturday"),C17<711,6.14*I17)
this part of the formula---------------^
returns value in case the condition is true
```

but what you specified there is a comparison which, of course, cannot return numeric value. Are you sure about "C17<711"?

Comment: =IF(C10<711,5.12  This is actual and i get correct result for the same but once i add OR to make deferent rates per hour based on C17<711,6.14 in between normal days and weekend by OR like  =IF(OR(E17="Friday",E17="Saturday"),C17<711,6.14*I17) the result comes true or false on Friday and Saturday, normal days have no issue with result but weekend.

Comment: @ABTechnic Sorry but I don't follow what you're trying to achieve. Can you, please, describe the *whole formula* in plain English using "if-then-or" words?

Comment: Thank you for you best cooperation.    =IF(C6<711,5.12)  C6 is employee basic salary which is 710, i argued if employee salary is less than 711 then i want 5.12 to come in this cell and this working properly, but this argument is for normal days now i want to add a formula in the same cell for Holy days  =IF(C6<711,6.14), so i need actually different rate for normal days and holy days.  Thanks & regards

Comment: =IF(OR(C10<711,E10="Friday",C10<711,E10="Saturday"),6.14*I10,IF(OR(E10="SUNDAY",E10="MONDAY"),5.14*I10))   i have this formula but this is not working based on basic salary

Comment: What I understand from your description is:
`if salary < 711 and day = workday then cell = 5.12; 
if salary < 711 and day = weekend then cell = 6.14`
What's still missing is what happens when salary >= 711.

Comment: in case of  >=711 that, it's another argument, but now I need  =IF(OR(C10<711,E10="Friday",C10<711,E10="Saturday"),6.14*I10,IF(OR(E10="SUNDAY",E10="MONDAY"),5.14*I10)) to work based on if cell=710

Comment: if salary < 711 and day = workday then cell = 5.12;  if salary < 711 and day = weekend then cell = 6.14 you caught now what actually i need now i want these two arguments I want to fix in the same column is it possible.

Comment: If salary does not change take it out of the formula and just use `=IF(OR(E17="Friday",E17="Saturday"), 6.14, 5.12)`